ckeditor5 DropdownField label does not update
Within a drupal module, a custom plugin has been created. I am using the advanced plugin walkthru from ck5 docs to implement a contextual balloon.
Objective: Have a dropdown populate its button label so that a user can see the selection made.

has my attempt at binding to the label within that field but does nothing after clicking an option
WORKS but is now permanently set for any future balloons a user might insert.

How can i achieve this basic task so that users can see a field get updated after clicking?
The contextual balloon has a dropdown like so...
view.js
const headerOptions = [
  ['none', 'None'],
  ['first_row', 'First Row'],
  ['first_column', 'First Column'],
  ['both', 'Both'],
];
export default class FormView extends View {
  constructor(locale) {
   this.headerRowsView = this._createDropdown('Headers', headerOptions);
   this.headerRowsView.items = headerOptions;
    
    // 1. my attempt at trying to bind
    this.headerRowsView.fieldView.buttonView.bind('label').to(this, 'styleOption', value => {
       return value ? value : 'none'
    });
   
   this.headerRowsView.fieldView.on('execute', evt => {
      const { id, label } = evt.source;
      this.headerRowsViewValue = id;
      /// 2. This works almost but its permanent for all balloons appearing
      //this.headerRowsView.fieldView.buttonView.label = label;
      //this.headerRowsView.fieldView.class = 'ck-dropdown-selected';
    });
    this.childViews = this.createCollection([
      this.headerRowsView,
    ]);
    this._focusCycler = new FocusCycler({ ... });
    this.setTemplate({ ... });
  }
  _createDropdown(label, options) {
    const dropdown = new LabeledFieldView(this.locale, createLabeledDropdown);
    const bind = this.bindTemplate;
    dropdown.set({
      label: label,
      class: 'ck-table-form__style-options'
    });
    dropdown.fieldView.buttonView.set({
      isOn: true,
      withText: true,
    });

    // **** It would be nice to bind the label here to return the value

    const opts_collection = this._createDropdownItems(options);
    addListToDropdown(dropdown.fieldView, opts_collection, {
      role: 'menu',
      tooltip: 'Options'
    });
    return dropdown;
  }
   _createDropdownItems(options) {
     const items = new Collection();
     options.forEach(opt => {
      items.add({
        type: 'button',
        model: new Model({
          withText: true,
          label: opt[1],
          id: opt[0],
        }),
      });
    });
    return items;
  }
}

